# S3TransferManager download image

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've managed to upload images to an S3 server using the S3TransferManager. now I'm trying to download the images back again. But I keep getting this log message. which I don't know how to solve. Seems like something is wrong with the file path so it creates a temp file.

```
[S3TransferManager filePath:]|531|File created to persist transfer request: /private/var/mobile/Applications/9CD874D1-2605-4067-949C-D373E917B85E/tmp/S3TransferDownloadRequests/000000000-individualframes-20131111T181238Z.plist
```

Here's the code I'm using.

```
- (void) downloadFramesFromURLS:(NSMutableArray *) urls {

    for (NSString *string in urls) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:string];
        S3GetObjectRequest *req = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:string withBucket:@"individualframes"];
        req.targetFilePath = filePath;
        req.contentType =  @"image/jpeg";
        req.delegate = self;
        [self.downLoadManager download:req];
    }

}
```

If I do `[self.s3 getObject:req];`instead of `[self.downLoadManager download:req];` the download works fine.But I'd like to use the transfer manager like I do with the uploads

UPDATE:
here's a simplified version of the code I'm using in the delegate method. so when the download is complete I want to use the downloaded data file and turn in back into an UIImage. response.body is nil when I use the transfer manager.

```
- (void) request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response {
            NSData *data = response.body;
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            // further processing goes on here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The log message you are seeing is because S3TransferManager creates a temporary metadata file so if the transfer is paused or interrupted it can be resumed.  This metadata file is removed on completion of the download. The actual file should download to the targetFilePath you specified.  Is it just the log line you are concerned about or did the file not download to targetFilePath?

This blog post describes the latest S3TransferManager functionality and may be of use to you: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2W0CZSJXOFBEU/Download-Pause-and-Resume-with-the-S3TransferManager-for-iOS

Comment: I'm trying to use the `response.body`of the `request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didCompleteWithResponse:(AmazonServiceResponse *)response` delegate method. that way, whenever the file is finished downloading I can process is further. the problem is that when I use the transfer manager, I get the impression that the file downloads but the response body is nil. but when I do it directly with the s3 amazon client the response.body is not nil and can be used further without any problem.